# How to see a list of all pages in Visio 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

The pages are as tabs at the bottom of the screen, and it's very uncomfortable when you have 100 pages and you are looking for a specific one.

Is there a better way to look through all this pages like in a list or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does this help:

1. Enabling the Developer Tab: Visio Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Customize the Ribbon -> Main Tabs -> Check “Developer” tree node (or check 'Run in developer mode' Advanced section)
2. Developer Tab should now be visible in Ribbon
3. Click "drawing explorer window"
4. You should see all tabs listed in Foreground pages, double clicking any page should take you to that page

Also, Just noticed this: Right click on the small forward backward buttons to the left of the page tabs(status bar) pops a list of the pages in the document :)

Comment: Ah, Kishor you beat me to it. I thought it might have that feature which is the same as in Excel to view multiple worksheets, but I don't have the beta installed at the moment since rebuilding my machine for Windows 7 RC > RTM.
It's mentioned here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/visio/archive/2009/12/10/improvements-to-multi-page-document-support-in-visio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Does Visio 2010 still have the "Reorder Pages" option when you right-click the page tab name? If so this will give you a list of all the pages in the document.

Comment: it has, but when i click it, i don't have any pages to order

Comment: but if i add some pages myself, than they appear in that list, not the existing ones though

Answer (score 0):

You could try printing them as PDF (you could try [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), for example). It's not ideal, but it might be a bit better if you only need to view and not edit.

Answer (score 0):

I have a utility that may help you with this:

http://www.sandrila.co.uk/visio-utilities/

menu SuperUtils -> Page -> List/Goto Page

Can also save the list of pages to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Make the pages foreground instead of background and you will able to see pages in "reorder Pages" property after right click on single tab. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To open the **Page** dialog box, press `Shift`+`F4`.

Found this in the Microsoft [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-visio-ee952f31-7e3e-4564-8116-f3ecbb733cc1) that applies to 2010 and newer.